# Regex for multiple mentioned username in text

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

This is my regex for usernames:

```
/^(?=.{3,20}$)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[.|_][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/i
```

It is matching single usernames correctly, like `tom.hardy`. But I want to match multiple usernames with preceding `@` character. Like the below text:

```
const text = "Hello @tom.hardy have you met with @john.deo1";
```

P.S: Please don't recommend [`twitter-text`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-text) npm;

Comment: just add a '@' match in front of your regexp ?

Comment: `[@][A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[.|_][A-Za-z0-9]+)*`

I have already tried this. its working without username character limits.
username characters limit is min 3, max 20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `@` at the beginning of the regex.

I also removed the anchors for matching inside a string and simplified case because of the case insensitive flag.

```js
var text = "Hello @tom.hardy have you met with @john.deo1";
var pattern = /@(?=.{3,20}(?:\s|$))[a-z][a-z0-9]+(?:[._][a-z0-9]+)?/ig;
var usernames = text.match(pattern);
console.log(usernames);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const text = "Hello @tom.hardy have you met with @john.deo1";
var pattern = /@[A-Za-z0-9._-]*/g;
const username = text.match(pattern); // ["@tom.hardy", "@john.deo1"]
```

Comment: I have limitation in username characters limit is  min 3, max 20